# Serializing Data Structures With Uniform Maps into CSV

Tags: java, csv, jackson, jackson-databind

I have to serialize objects similar to this:

```
public class Something {
    String id;

    Map<String, String> name;
    Map<String, String> description;
}
```

The fields `name` and `description` are internationalized.  The keys are locale identifiers ("fr", "en-US", "en-UK", "de", ...), the values are the respective values for that locale.

The header line of the expected CSV must look like this:

```
id,name.fr,name.en-US,description.fr,description.en-US
```

If have omitted the other languages for brevity.

`@JsonUnwrapped` does not seem to help because it would generate the same keys "fr", "en-US", ... for all properties.

Is there any way to achieve that with Jackson out of the box?  It would be acceptable to hard-code the list of locale identifiers supported.

There is more mischief ahead.  Another class to be serialized will look like this:

```
public class SomethingElse {
    String id;

    Map <String, Feature> features;
}

public class Feature {
    Map <String, String> feature;
}
```

Each `SomethingElse` has values for the features "color", "taste", ... in each of the languages "fr", "en-US", "en-UK", "de", ... The resulting CSV must look like this:

```
id,color.fr,color.en-US,taste.fr,taste.en-US,...
```

The list of locale identifiers is the same across all use cases.

One possible approach could be to serialize into JSON first, and then "flatten" that JSON so that it can be easily serialized into CSV.  By "flattening" I mean that conversion:

```
{
  "foo": {
    "bar": {
      "a": 1,
      "b": 2
    }
  }
}
```

into:

```
{
  "foo.bar.a": 1,
  "foo.bar.b": 2
}
```

In other words: the key for each leaf value will become the JavaScript code needed to access it in the original data structure.  Is there a library method that can do such a conversion?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that this is not supported as of version 2.9.4, see https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-dataformats-text/tree/master/csv:

> Future improvements:
>   ...
>   Mapping of nested POJOs using dotted notation (similar to @JsonUnwrapped, but without requiring its use